# Python 3 MySQL find number of rows error?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have tried several variation of this, and for that reason I am coming here for guidance. Where is this incorrect?

```
with connection.cursor() as cur:
    sql = 'select * from table where var1 = %s, var2 = %s, var3 = %s, var4 = %s, var5 = %s'
        cur.execute(sql, (var1val, var2val, var3val, var4val, var5val))
        connection.commit()
        l_fetch = cur.fetchall()
        rc = int(l_fetch.rowcount)
        print('rc len lerr_log: ' + rc)
        if(rc > 0):
            #result found
```

Comment: I don't think you need `connection.commit()` for `SELECT` queries, only queries that make changes.

Answer (score 0):

`cur.fetchall()` returns a list, it doesn't have a `rowcount` attribute.

The number of rows is `cur.rowcount` and `len(l_fetch)`.